# Unable to determine the cause of the "ORA-00922: missing or invalid option" error

Tags: oracle, syntax-error, schema, talend

I am getting "ORA-00922: missing or invalid option" error when I try to run a Talend job to load data from an Oracle script to a database table

The script itself has been tested and successfully runs in the Oracle SQL editor, as well as within Talend

Does anyone know why I may be getting the error when I run the load job in Talend?

A quick lookup of this error on the internet shows this:

ORA-00922: missing or invalid option occurs if an invalid option is specified while defining a storage clause or column. Oracle provides the following information about this error:

Cause: The valid option in specifying a column is NOT NULL to specify that the column cannot contain any NULL values. Only constraints may follow the datatype. Specifying a maximum length on a DATE or LONG datatype also causes this error.

If we can assume for a moment that the error is from the SCHEMA, does anyone see anything wrong with this schema?

- The "Column" and "Type" columns belong to the data source: the Oracle SQL script
- The "DB Column" and "DB Type" columns belong to the Oracle DB table where the data is supposed to load into

[image]

Here's the destination table's definition taken directly from Oracle. The table name is Payments

[image]

The destination table already exists. When I run an insert script directly into the table, at first I get the message: Error at Command Line : 6 Column : 17 Error report - SQL Error: ORA-00984: column not allowed here. The item at Line 6, column 17 happens to be the Program Code.

When I put a quote around the Program Code's value (as well as the date values), the insert works. The non-nullable fields are being populated, and the appropriate error message is shown if I try inserting NULL into the non-nullable fields

Here is an insert script that works:

```
INSERT INTO PAYMENTS 
(CLAIMANT_ID, CLAIM_ID, PROGRAM_CODE, BWE_DATE, PROCESS_DATE, DEPOSIT_DATE,
GROSS_AMOUNT,CLAIMANT_NET_AMOUNT, FEDERAL_TAXES, STATE_LOCAL_TAXES, OP_OFFSET, 
 OOS_OP_OFFSET, CHILD_SUPPORT, OOS_CS, FPUC, LWA)
VALUES
(123456,54321,'ABC','24-OCT-20','01-JAN-21','04-JAN-21',149,128,15,6,0,0,0,0,0,0)
```

Comment: I don't know Talend. However, what happens if you remove **Date pattern**?

Comment: I just tried that. Did not make a difference. The same error still showed

Comment: The only chance: try to find the `create table` statement somewhere in the logs and see what is wrong. Good Luck!

Comment: That Oracle error is very generic and so not very helpful when trying to debug the problem. Does the target table already exist or is your Talend job creating it? If it doesn't exist then try creating it directly in Oracle and running the Talend job again. If the table does exist already, then check that the non-nullable columns are all being populated in the Talend job

Comment: @marmite bomber, I'm not sure how to do that, but I will check with our DBA on that

Comment: @NickW, The table already exists. When i run an insert script directly into the table, at first I get the message: 
Error at Command Line : 6 Column : 17
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00984: column not allowed here. 
The item at Line 6, column 17 happens to be the Program Code. When I put a quote around the Program Code's value (as well as the date values), the insert works. The non-nullable fields are being populated, and the appropriate error message is shown if I try inserting NULL into the non-nullable fields

Comment: Please can you provide (in your question, not in the comments) (1) the table definition taken directly from Oracle (not from Talend) (2) An example of an insert statement that works when run directly in Oracle (only needs one record). Thanks

Comment: @nickw, I just did. My question has been updated

Comment: Hi - that INSERT script cannot work as you are trying to insert NULL into CLAIM_ID - which is a NOT NULL column

Comment: @NickW My bad. I didn't intend to have NULL there. I have changed it to 54321

Comment: did you try emptying your 'Default' column containing 'null' ? Not sure Talend manages this well.

Comment: @corentin, the cause of the error has been identified. I had put a semi-colon at the end of the script (as one would normally do when you write an SQL query.) But in Talend, the entire script starts and ends with the double-quote. You cannot have the semi-colon after the script, and then end with the double quote. Once the semi-colon was removed, the error went away

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for all your help, the cause of the error has been identified. I had put a semi-colon at the end of the script (as one would normally do when you write an SQL query.) But in Talend, the entire script starts and ends with the double-quote. You cannot have the semi-colon after the script, and then end with the double quote. Once the semi-colon was removed, the error went away

[image]